# What software is used for user flow?

Tags: users, software, flow

Does anyone know what software is used to make this user flow?

[image]

I got the pic from Google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about software suggestion

Answer (score 1):

the software is Sketch Sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You can use any software that draws boxes, arrows and annotations. Even powerpoint is feasible. Axure, sketch, etc all valid.